# In the Double Slit Experiment, what is the longest time $T$ recorded between shots of particles, electrons, photons, etc.?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment

How can we be certain that electrons fired do not leave some kind of residual interference for the next shot?

What is the longest time recorded between shots?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'residual interference'?

Comment: I just mean how can we be certain that a particle fired doesn't have an impact on its environment, which in turn could impact the next particle.

If a train went right by me, the wind would continue to blow and I would continue to feel chilly even after it has passed me by.  Similarly if I throw a rock straight down into the pond, it will create some waves which could alter the trajectory of another rock I throw again in quick succession.  The longer the time recorded between shots of particles, I imagine the greater confidence we would have that particles fired in succession are independent

Comment: We can never be 100% sure of anything. However, if we perform the experiment in vacuum the result is the same. Hence, it comes down what "environmental effects" are allowed in a vacuum. You can certainly come up with *adhoc fixes*, however, as you probably know the value of a theory is measured in how easy it is falsified. So ask yourself, how could we falsify your "environmental effects"? In addition, what would be the benefit in using "environmental effects"? Are you able to predict the outcome of other (new) experiments?

Answer (score 3):

We know that there is no residual interference because the pattern does not depend on the size of the interval between photons. If you load up the slits with a really bright laser you get the same thing if you gradually turn down the intensity.

Also, the pattern does not depend on the material of the slits, so long as the required opaque parts are opaque and the required transparent parts are transparent. All that matters is the geometry. So any possible residual does not hang around on any particular material. Iron, carbon, the edge of your finger, fibers of hair, photographic emulsion from old-style photographic film, medical hypodermic needles, all of these produce the expected diffraction pattern.

Also, shining one laser in this direction, and another in that direction, makes no difference. So any residual interference would have to have a memory for directions.

Also, shining a red laser and a green laser at the same time makes no difference. So any residual inteference would have to have a memory for wavelength.

Also, diffraction works as expected for widely different wavelengths. Everything from quite long radio waves to quite hard x-rays diffract as expected. So any residual interference would have to function over this range of wavelengths.

So this increasingly unlikely residual would have to work for arbitrary intensities, last for very long times, spread over the entire length of the slits, only work for photons of the exact right energy coming from the correct direction, work for slits made of any material, and work for energy from many-meters radio waves to many-MeV x-rays.

[Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzbKb59my3U) did the experiment with about 100 photons per second. This gives an average distance between photons of 3000 km. That is, since his equipment was about 2 meters long, there was less than one chance in 1 million of any given photon overlapping with its neighbor. He had a lot of background (about 7 photons per second) polluting the pattern but he still got it. He has better equipment than my highschool did, but it wasn't all that good.

Answer (score 0):

Two-slit experiment is mainly a pedagogical device to teach the basics of QM, demonstrating the wave nature of electrons. In this sense it is better studied alongside the two-slit experiment for classical light (aka *diffraction on a slit). Many of the restricting assumptions, such as those concerning the particles being non-interacting or obeying Fermi-Dirac /Bose-Einstein statistics can be lifted, and indeed studied - e g., in solid-state Aharonov-Bohm interferometers. In fact, there is a range of peculiar phenomena appearing in such interferometers, having to do with their realistic realization - phase rigidity, phase lapses, etc. - some having simple explanation and others having required deeper research to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In the typical double slit experiment the electron source is a cathode , even for single electrons at a time, and thus an incoherent beam, so your "residual interference" cannot be from the incoming beam. In your comment you explain:

> I just mean how can we be certain that a particle fired doesn't have an impact on its environment, which in turn could impact the next particle.

The [size of the electron footprints ,](http://www.diyphysics.com/2013/04/02/in-memoriam-dr-akira-tonomura-1942-2012/) where all the energy is expended on the atoms of the screen in dimension of microns, a good distance apart preclude the residual interference to come from the screen. Any residual interference will come from the "slits" . If you read the link you will see the experimental set up for the single electron at a time experiment.

For the single photon double slit I agree with the answer of Dan, and would add that if the single photon had  left an appreciable imprint on the slits,it would lose energy and change frequency, which is not observed. I suppose a limit could be calculated by the fact that the frequency is invariant.

Comment: Could it be possible that electrons emit electromagnetism or give off some kind of energy that could influence other electrons fired immediately?

Comment: @BjornT. If they did emit enough photons ( that is what emission of electromagnetism means for electrons) they would lose/change  their energy and thus the probability frequency pattern would be destroyed. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/debrog2.html

Answer (score 0):

You assume that spacetime is plastic, like skiers carving paths through the snow. I was told that this is not the case, in terms of current theory.

On the other hand, assume that the insides of the double-slit device are evacuated. Shoot a photon, let it collide with the sensor array. Then, flush the device with gas (like air), and re-evacuate before shooting the next photon. Does this affect the pattern on the sensor array over time? It was worth thinking about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is to be established that I first thought of this concept prior to the OP, but my line of reasoning is different and the seed of the idea I thought of between 2017-2019.

The idea takes the form of what I call the “Yearly Thought Experiment” of Dice rolling.

From my article,

“As a thought experiment, If you roll a die and then wait an entire year to roll another die, and then another year after that for a third roll, and you keep going to get to 6 years and beyond with one roll per year, how are you to calculate those probabilities?

Are you really going to go the route of Binomial Distribution, which would begin to conclude that some numbers have more or less of a chance to be rolled than others?

From my view, this cannot be true, as each roll is simply 1/6 probability for all sides per year. How can you possibly say that one number has any more likelihood than another, no matter how many rolls are collected into the data set?

Once you really grok this, then what difference is there between 6 rolls six years apart vs 6 rolls six minutes apart, or six seconds apart, or all 6 rolls simultaneously?

Wouldn’t it simply remain that each roll is equally 1/6 probability for all sides of the dice?

I am separating rolls by one roll per year to emphasize the independence of each individual roll.

If each side of a singular die has an equal 1/6 Probability for one particular roll, then each side must have a 1/6 equal probability for ALL rolls, which implies fungibility between them. Each roll is Singular. Each roll is independent. And yet, each roll is fungible, meaning that the arrangement of rolls is irrelevant to calculating its probability distribution.“

https://chsmithe22.medium.com/explaining-the-double-slit-experiment-with-the-roll-of-dice-and-coin-flips-second-rough-draft-ae81b167de69

This line of reasoning I am now carrying over to the double slit experiment. The reason I propose for that the interference pattern would disappear is as follows:

The underlying idea is that if you extend the Time interval, the more that you preserve the  Absolute Independence of the Event.

The more the Absolute Independence is preserved, the more the particle aspect is extracted out of the wave-particle duality.

Therefore, the photon should be able to collapse the wave function without even measuring which slit it goes through, simply by exploring the Time Factor. Some length of Time has to be able to preserve Absolute Independence of the photon and remove it from the wave pattern. That's the theory.

*For the record, my theory is that increasing the Time interval to some critical point in between the firing of photons will remove the interference pattern, even without measuring/detecting which slit they travel through.*

And since the seed of these ideas was spawned in between 2017-2019, it is I who first thought of this concept, not the OP. I will go to great lengths to find proof of thinking of the Yearly Thought Experiment of Dice prior to the OP’s post if needed.

Comment: Actually the OP had it correct but just backwards ....the "residual interference" is actually "initial interference" i.e. there is a pattern in space that guides the photon before it is emitted.  The EM field is very dynamic and all photons originate as/from excited electrons .... these excitded electrons are long time active in the EM field before the photon is  created/initiated/emitted/guided.

Comment: And absolutely no (by absolutely I mean the sum total of all physics knowledge to date), the time between emissions does not matter.  Each emission process (including the excited electron part) is independent .... with some exceptions like stimulated emission and a few others.

Comment: If each emission is independent, then that is my reasoning for why the interference pattern would eventually disappear. Each Event IS independent, and that’s exactly why I think the issue could be forced by extending the time intervals far enough. What needs to be established is what is the longest length of time in between the firing of each photon up to the present moment in all of physics. Nobody actually bothered answering this question from the OP. My guess would be that nobody really knows, as tests likely haven’t focused on the Time Factor.

Comment: That's the whole point of the worlds physics knowledge to date  ..... the "interference" does NOT disappear and never will.  You can search my posts about Feynman's path integral ..... it basically says waves are resonant ... like on a guitar string .... EM waves (virtual and/or real) travel paths that have path lengths that are integer multiples of the wavelength .... just like the guitar string.  And this math is totally backed up by measurements of the double slit pattern and multi-slit patterns etc.

Comment: Saying that the interference never disappears and never will sounds close to Science Dogma. Never say never. Especially in science. The question remains, *what is the longest recorded interval of time per emission of photons being fired off one at a time in an experiment?”*

Comment: I’m aware that it never has so far when not detecting the slit, but declaring that it never will shouldn’t be done. It actually does disappear anyway already, simply by making a detection of which slit the photon goes through.

Comment: Never is a real possibility. !